# Is the PID of the current PHP script a good identifier to use for concurrent database requests?

Tags: php, database, pid

I have a need to process a table using multiple PHP processes. I've read about good practices to do this, one of which is to update x amount of rows, setting the `pid` column to the processes's current PID, then doing an update where `pid` = getmypid().

Is PID a good unique value to use? On my development machine (using xampp), I just ran the same script at the same time, and the PID was the same for each... so no uniqueness there.

Is there a better identifier to use that would also allow me to check if a process has been killed or not? If one of the scripts dies, I'll need to be able to detect that with another script in order reset the appropriate `PID` columns back to `null`.

Comment: The database is more than able to handle the concurrency stuff for itself

Comment: There are various forms of concurrency controls built into modern databases. There's probably a common solution already available for what you're trying to do. But without knowing what that is exactly, it's hard to advice anything suitable.

Comment: Depends also on the size of your data set, if you don't need to use multiple processes then don't over complicate it?

Comment: Can you point me to some concurrency controls built into MySQL? My need is to regularly go through every row in a table and perform some actions with each of them. As the table grows larger, I will be constrained by the speed of the process. I'd like to learn how I can go through the database faster using multiple scripts. What does MySQL provide to accomplish this?